# Can't import component in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and trying out my first app with expo-cli, I'm trying to use react navigation to jump between screens but I'm having problems trying to import my screen components, namely HomeScreen.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to resolve "/screens/HomeScreen.js" from "App.js"
```

My folder structure is as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVv6U.png

This is my App.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from '/screens/HomeScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home: HomeScreen
},
{
  initialRouteName:'Home',
  defaultNavigationOptions:
  {
    title:'App'
  }

}
);
```

My HomeScreen component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


export default function HomeScreen()
{
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Pero esto que es</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
```

Adding `./` in the beginning means you start navigating inside the folder you are in.

If you need go back one step outside, you should add `../`

So from `App.js`, now you need to navigate your way to the folder where your `HomeScreen` is in.